# Multiframe Ultrasound DICOM file creation

Tags: c++, c++17, dicom, dcmtk

I am new at DICOM and DCMTK. I have a set of BITMAP Ultrasound data that I would like to save as a lossless DICOM file.

After loadding the data in a queue `frame_queue` and setting all the mandatory DICOM necessary parameters for Ultrasound Multiframe images I realise a loop to add the images in the DcmDataset as follows:

```
std::unique_ptr<DcmDataset> dataset;

/*** 
DICOM parameters A setted not added here as many parameters are set
***/


std::shared_ptr<unsigned char[]> frame;
std::shared_ptr<RGBQUAD[]> colorTable;

DJEncoderRegistration::registerCodecs();
DJ_RPLossless params; // codec parameters, we use the defaults
// this causes the lossless JPEG version of the m_dataset to be created
    
/**/
E_TransferSyntax xfer = DcmXfer(EXS_JPEGProcess14).getXfer();
DcmPixelSequence* sequence = new DcmPixelSequence(DcmTag(DCM_PixelData, EVR_OB));
DcmPixelData* newPixelData = new DcmPixelData(DCM_PixelData);
dataset->insert(sequence, OFTrue);

OFstatic_cast(DcmPixelData*, newPixelData)->putOriginalRepresentation(xfer, NULL, sequence);

while (frame_queue.popFrame(frame, colorTable)) // we extract a new frame from the queue
{
    DcmPixelItem* newItem = new DcmPixelItem(DcmTag(DCM_Item, EVR_OB));
    if (newItem != NULL)
    {
        sequence->insert(newItem);
        /* put pixel data into the item */
        std::shared_ptr<Uint8[]> newDCMFrame;
        
        colorTableToRGB(frame, colorTable, newDCMFrame, m_frameWidth, m_frameHeight);
        result = newItem->putUint8Array((Uint8*)newDCMFrame.get(), m_frameHeight * m_frameWidth * 3).good(); // this returns true in my test
        frame.reset();
        colorTable.reset();
    }
}

dataset->chooseRepresentation(EXS_JPEGProcess14, &params); 
dataset->saveFile(path.c_str());
```

The call of `dataset->chooseRepresentation(EXS_JPEGProcess14, &params);` raises the error:

```
DcmDataset: Wrong class for pixel data element, cannot change representation
```

A DICOM File is saved but it is empty.

Does anyone know what's causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess but you are creating the dataset in uncompressed representation. In this case, the pixel data must NOT be represented as a sequence of frames. You should try calling `putUint8Array()` directly on the `DcmPixelData` element instead of inserting sequences to it.

DCMTK will change that way of encoding to the one you want to achieve directly, when you call `DcmDataset::chooseRepresentation()`.

For uncompressed pixel data, it is not allowed to used the "encapsulated" pixel data encoding with sequences, and I suspect that this is why `DcmDataset::chooseRepresentation()` complains about "not finding what was expected".

Comment: Thanks kritzel_sw, I will look into that and be back but one first remarque, It was under my understanding the  `putUint8Array()` was used only for a single frame as calling it multiple times would erase the previous image. Or I should give the buffer containing all frames once? [link](https://support.dcmtk.org/docs-360/classDcmPixelData.html#b268d4f2d7eb669be52e3d2d61807f6c)

Comment: @firehelm: True. One buffer for all frames would be one possible solution. If you are worried about memory consumption, there is also a possibility to assign and attribute's value chunk by chunk (in case of pixel data: frame by frame) from a DcmInputStream.

Comment: Memory should not be a problem as I devide a long stream into subfiles so I control the number of images present in the buffer. Now if I create a single DICOM buffer, I am guessing that I should copy the images in an object as `Uint8[imageSize * nbFrames] imagesBuffer` and then use an object `DcmPixelData* dcmData` and add the frames as `result = dcmData->putUint8Array(imagesBuffer, imageSize * nbFrames).good();`? But in this case how can dcmtk define a separation between the frames?

Comment: yes, exactly. a separation between frames is only needed in an encapsulated representation. For uncompressed multi-frame data, the size of a frame is defined by the corresponding header elements: Rows, Columns, BitsAllocated and (for color images) SamplesPerPixel

Comment: So I think this is going on a good path for now as the new error is `True lossless encoder: Unable to get relevant attributes from dataset` I am guessing that some DICOM Tags are missing, I am scanning through tags from other Multiframe US that I have to see which ones are missing and found `(0028,0004) CS RGB                                               # 1, 4 Photometric Interpretation` looking into this I saw that `RGB` can be replaced by `PALETTE COLOR`. I am guessing then that I can avoid converting my palette color images to RGB images.

Comment: Yes you can directly encode the image in PALETTE_COLOR and though I never tried it, I am confident that DCMTK will handle it in the conversion (if DICOM allows compression of palette color images at all). But if you do so: do not miss to encode the color palette in the DICOM header. After reading how this is done in DICOM you may want to revisit the idea of converting to RGB :-D

Comment: @kritzel_sw For reasons of completeness: Only recently, an "uncompressed encapsulated Transfer Syntax for encoding very large pixel data sets​" has been added to the DICOM standard with CP-2083​. It is not yet supported by the DCMTK but listed as "Conformance #1000" in our issue tracker: https://support.dcmtk.org/redmine/issues/1000

Comment: Thanks @J.Riesmeier for pointing us to this. This is an interesting extension, and I am more than curious if and when this will make it into product implementations.

Comment: Hi, I did the previous changes and now while calling `dataset->saveFile(path.c_str());` saves an empty file. I tried to define `DcmFileFormat pDcmFile(m_dataset.get());` and call `OFCondition status = pDcmFile.saveFile(path.c_str(), EXS_JPEGProcess14);`, the status returns `0x7942c410 Pixel representation not found`

Comment: And to which value did you set the attribute Pixel Representation (0028,0103)?

Comment: I indeed had some compatibility issues between the RGB format and the pixel representation. So now I finaly was able to save a single frame in the dicom. Now if I put three frames, the dicom file is of same size and has only one frame. I tried to modify the `Number of Frames Attribute (0028,0008) = 3` and it did not change anything.

Comment: It may make sense to open a new question for this. You are probably doing it differently than the current code you put into the OP. My first suspect would be that you repeatedly assign pixel data to the DcmPixelData which overwrites the existing. I do not know from the top of my head if there are other options. But adding all frames to one buffer that is subsequently assigned to DcmPixelData should work.

Answer (score 1):

So I finaly got it to work:

```
std::unique_ptr<DcmDataset> dataset;

/*** 
DICOM parameters A setted not added here as many parameters are set
***/


std::shared_ptr<unsigned char[]> frame;
std::shared_ptr<RGBQUAD[]> colorTable;

DJEncoderRegistration::registerCodecs();
DJ_RPLossless params; // codec parameters, we use the defaults
// this causes the lossless JPEG version of the m_dataset to be created
    
/**/
E_TransferSyntax xfer = DcmXfer(EXS_JPEGProcess14).getXfer();

DcmPixelData* newPixelData = new DcmPixelData(DCM_PixelData);
dataset->insert(newPixelData , OFTrue);


bool result = true;
static const int imageSize = m_frameWidth * m_frameHeight * 3;
std::shared_ptr<Uint8[]> imagesBufferPtr(new Uint8[imageSize * m_nbFrames], array_deleter<Uint8>());

std::vector<std::vector<Uint8>> dataImages(m_nbFrames, std::vector<Uint8>(imageSize));

int frameId = 0;

while (this->popFrame(frame, colorTable) == cwlibdicom::frameBufferStatus::BUFFER_SUCCESS && result)
{
    Uint8 *img = imagesBufferPtr.get();
    img = &img[frameId];
    colorTableToRGB(frame, colorTable, img, m_frameWidth, m_frameHeight);

    std::memcpy(&imagesBufferPtr.get()[frameId * imageSize], img.data(), imageSize);

    frameId++;
    frame.reset();
    colorTable.reset();
}
result = newPixelData->putUint8Array(imagesBufferPtr.get(), imageSize * m_nbFrames).good();
header->setProperty(DCM_NumberOfFrames, nb_frame);
header->setProperty(DCM_SamplesPerPixel, "3");
header->setProperty(DCM_PhotometricInterpretation, "RGB");
header->setProperty(DCM_Rows, m_imageHeight);
header->setProperty(DCM_Cols, m_imageWidth);
header->setProperty(DCM_BitsAllocated, "8");
header->setProperty(DCM_BitsStored, "8");
header->setProperty(DCM_HighBit, "7");
header->setProperty(DCM_PixelRepresentation, "0");
header->setProperty(DCM_FrameIncrementPointer, "(0018, 1065)\\(F9E4, 3317)"); // Found this in a multiframe image that already existed.

dataset->chooseRepresentation(EXS_JPEGProcess14, &params); 
dataset->saveFile(path.c_str(), EXS_JPEGProcess14);
```